# No notification sent when distributing iOS build through Fabric plugin

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I have been distributing iOS builds through Fabric plugin it works awesome.But very recently I am facing a problem while distributing the iOS build to my testers through Fabric.When I distribute any new build it says "uploaded successfully" but none of my testers are receiving email notification about the new build. some times it isn't allowing me to select the testers instead it always showing "9(I have added 9 testers) people have access to this build". I tried changing iOS app version and distributed new version but still could not see email notification. Some times it is notifying  testers  after 10  minutes. Is any thing  wrong in the process that I am doing? Thank you.

Comment: How much time does they take to approve a new member?

Comment: It took me 1 hour to distribute a iOS build to newly added member

Comment: I would like to help but I just got accepted after a couple of minutes, thanks.

Comment: Same exact issue that I'm having

Comment: I have the same issue. Were someone able to figure out the problem?